# Doctrine not hydrating entity correctly (ids are strings instead of integers)

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to map a legacy database to some new entities. Two entities `Wishlist` and `Product` have a many to many relationship, so there is a pivot table that has to be mapped as an entity `WishlistProduct` with many-to-one associations on both sides.

The relationship looks like:

```
┌──────────┐  M:1  ┌─────────────────┐  1:M  ┌─────────┐
│ Wishlist │───────│ WishlistProduct │───────│ Product │
└──────────┘       └─────────────────┘       └─────────┘
```

However, Doctrine keeps hydrating `Product::$id` with a string of the id column and all the other fields are NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because although the `Wishlist::$wishlistProducts` property is correctly assigned a new instance of `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`, the same has not been done for `Product::$wishlistProducts` and so if that value is NULL, the entity cannot be hydrated correctly.

Whenever you creating your own psuedo many-to-many relationship, make sure both entities have:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class EntityOnOneSideOfRelationship
{
    private $pivotEntity;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pivotEntity = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```